# How to add fractional offset in moment?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, iso

I want to convert the date string to ISO format below. I can get the date string as follows. But my expected value is different.

```
moment().format();                                // "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" (ISO 8601, no fractional seconds)
```

expecting format

```
2022-11-23T01:02:58.3223378
```

How to get the expected format?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) you can choose the format that you want in output:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS')
```